# NSConstraints Right Align Textfield Inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I am adding a UITextField to a UITableViewCell and right aligning it via the following constraints:

```
[cell addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tf attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell.textLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1 constant:8]];
[cell addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tf attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:8]];
[cell addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tf attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:-8]];
[cell addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tf attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1 constant:-16]];
```

This works great, until I rotate the View. The UITextField doesn't keep far right snug against the cell. Am I just missing a constraint?

Comment: It's not clear... but your first constraint is setting `tf`'s leading edge relative to `cell.textLabel` trailing edge with a gap of 8pts. And your last constraint has `tf`'s trailing set to `cell.contentView`'s trailing with a 16pt difference

Comment: Just to point out what Louis said, you add constraints to the contentView, not the cell. Also, if you're using iOS 8 and above, you'll want to activate the constraint via rightConstraint.active = YES;

Answer (score 0):

FYI I added:

```
cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

To the UITableCell and it fixed it!

Comment: this works, but you're no longer using autolayout if that was a goal?